# Issue passing array to field

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, iview-ui

I would like to show all permissions associated to the role i am editing. issue is i dont get a value but when i console. log the issue it seems to exist

[image]

```
showEditModal(role,index) {
      role.permissions.push(role.permissions.id)
      let obj = {
               id: role.id,
               name: role.name,
               permissions: role.permissions
      };
      console.log(role.permissions)
      this.editData = obj;
      this.editModal = true;
      this.index = index;
    },
```

this is my code where i would to get an array of data in my edit form, any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

well i think that you are passing editData to the modal component as a prop, and when you are setting editModal to true, it has not been passed yet,
try using $nextTick for setting editModal to true, it might fix your problem.

```
this.$nextTick().then(() => {
    this.editModal = true;
});
```

Comment: the issue is that i want populate the data with existing fields in my edit form i could